# Is there a way to prevent usage of any

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

Is there a way that Typescript can be made to throw an error an not compile if a variable/ function is defined without the correct types or if type any is used? i.e.

```
let var1 = 0;  --> Throw error
let var2: any; --> Throw error
let var3: number = 3;  --> OK

getNumber() {  --> Throw error
  return var3;
}

getNumber(): number {  --> OK
  return var3;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use TSLint in your project you can turn on following rule: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-any

Comment: Judging from the [source code of *no-any*](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/blob/master/src/rules/noAnyRule.ts), you might have to use the `noImplicitAny` compiler option as well.